# Android Multiple Screen Support not working

Tags: android, xml, screen

I created my application in only one layout. but now I need to support high resolution screens. I have a `ListView` getting images from `JSON`.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="174dp"
```

Images are shown good size on 4 inch device, but on tablet images are cropped from top and bottom. so i added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ellidokuz.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens  
android:resizeable="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
/>
```

this code to manifest. then copied `list_v.xml` to `drawable-xhdi` and `drawable-xxhdi`.
and then I changed

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="174dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="350dp"
```

but still my application running the xml file in the layout folder. How can I set it to run xml file in `drawable-xxhdpi` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put your `XML` layout file into `drawable` folders!!

Instead just just put it in:

```
layout-small
layout-large
layout-xlarge
...
```

Answer (score 2):

just simple copy and paste your xml into different Layout folders

[image: check this]

Answer (score 1):

There is some convention to achieve this as per google developers blog recommended. If you want to achieve your layout should work for both phones and tablets then there is a way to do is, create different folders for layout like layout-small, layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, put your xml file into all the folders, but you must have same drawables folders as well with different sizes of images.

Refer this : [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

High-resolution screens exists in different screen sizes. That means you should create different layout folder like layout-sw720dp for 10-inch tablets. Then you should create a corresponding drawable folder like drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi were you can put your pictures in. I wrote a blog about this. It covers more than your question and should help getting you started. 
http://objectofclasshuman.blogspot.de/2014/04/android-user-interface.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope it is more useful now.