# Android app supporting screen sizes/densities

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I recently wrote a small android app and am having a hard time getting to the layout to scale on other devices. I wrote it for and tested it with my Galaxy S3.

To test it on other devices I had to use AVD's. I use a layout file and provide dimens.xml for each screen density (values-mdpi, values-hdpi etc.)

This only works for the screen size of the AVD I was testing on. If I use an AVD with the same screen ***density*** but a different screen ***size***, the layout gets whacky. Am I going to provide a full set of dimensions for every device I want to support?

Such as **values-(screen size)-(screen density)-(orientation)** with every combination I want to support?

Here is my activity_main.xml layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:click="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<click.CustomFontTextView
    android:id="@+id/click_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textView_title_margintop"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textView_title_textsize"
    click:fontName="freescript.ttf" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_newgame"
    style="@style/clickMenuButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_newgame_margintop"
    android:onClick="newGame"
    android:text="@string/button_newgame" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_highscore"
    style="@style/clickMenuButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_highscore_margintop"
    android:onClick="highScore"
    android:text="@string/button_highscore" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_quit"
    style="@style/clickMenuButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_quit_marginTop"
    android:onClick="showInsertitial"
    android:text="@string/button_quit" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and dimens.xml from values-xhdpi/

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

<!-- Main Activity Layout -->
<dimen name="textView_title_textsize">145sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_title_margintop">125dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_newgame_margintop">390dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_highscore_margintop">455dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_quit_marginTop">520dp</dimen>

<!-- Game Activity Layout -->
<dimen name="textView_timer_textsize">80sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_timer_margintop">80dp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_clickcount_textsize">50sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_clickcount_margintop">510dp</dimen>

<!-- Dialog Layout -->
<dimen name="textView_dialogTitle_textsize">60sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_dialogTitle_padding">6dp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_dialogGOInfo_textsize">40sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_dialogGOInfo_padding">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_dialogHSInfo_textsize">70sp</dimen>
<dimen name="textView_dialogHSInfo_padding">5dp</dimen>

<!-- Menu Button -->
<dimen name="button_menubutton_textsize">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Any easy fix or am I going to have to write a million copies of dimens.xml?

Comment: follow this link...hope it work for you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196569/android-multiple-screen-support-not-working/23196986#23196986

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "the layout gets whacky".

Comment: The buttons appearing off screen or bunched up halfway up the screen  and the text being far too big or too small, I thought using dp & sp should stop that from happening?

Comment: @Amardeep that would require writing out a lot more layouts and dimensions which I would like to avoid if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing from a `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` and using `android:layout_weight` to maintain widget positions on all screen sizes and densities.

Answer (score 0):

Better use Linearlayout For Galaxy S3 Screen size resolution is 720*1280 XHDPI So you need create a folder name layout-xlarge or layout-sw320dp in your res folder. Hope this will help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:click="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <click.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/click_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textView_title_margintop"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textView_title_textsize"
        click:fontName="freescript.ttf" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_newgame"
        style="@style/clickMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_newgame_margintop"
        android:onClick="newGame"
        android:text="@string/button_newgame" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_highscore"
        style="@style/clickMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_highscore_margintop"
        android:onClick="highScore"
        android:text="@string/button_highscore" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_quit"
        style="@style/clickMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_quit_marginTop"
        android:onClick="showInsertitial"
        android:text="@string/button_quit" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Updated 1

> Provide different layouts for different screen sizes
>   By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current device screen. In most cases, this works fine. In other cases, your UI might not look as good and might need adjustments for different screen sizes. For example, on a larger screen, you might want to adjust the position and size of some elements to take advantage of the additional screen space, or on a smaller screen, you might need to adjust sizes so that everything can fit on the screen.
>   **The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.**
>   Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the sw<N>dp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in **layout-sw600dp/**. Using the new techniques for declaring layout resources is discussed further in the section about Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2.

From the Android [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) - just use layout-small/ layout-xlarge/ etc.. folder :=)
best way ever..

Comment: The layout works fine on Galaxy S3, I want to support other screen sizes/densities

Comment: You cannot use the same layout for other devices

Comment: Yes I tried this but then I get the same problem again because of screen densitites. A layout I make for sw320dp displays completely differently on a mdpi screen when compared to a xhdpi screen density

Comment: dont give  android:layout_marginTop in resource give separately for each screen then it will work because each screen is different you cant use the same size for all screens